# Can I install cPanel on other hardisk I mount on the server? Not from /home?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, storage, cpanel

Now I'm testing to install CentOS + cPanel/WHM on Amazon EC2.
My instance type is m3.xlarge (containing 2 * 40 GB SSD).
I already mount the 2 ephemeral storage in my instance.
ephemeral0 /media/ephemeral0
ephemeral1 /media/ephemeral1

But, there is a 5GB space that the whole CentOS system install on it.
When I'm going to install cPanel at /home directory, it will notice me that my server do not have enough space to install.

Is that install cPanel to the instance storage (ephemeral storage) is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel cannot be installed as specific instance based on a storage. It will compile many modules with Perl and Centos system.

Comment: Is that the best way is mount ephemeral storage to the specify directory that cpanel installed before installation?